# Methods in test in parallel way

Tags: java, eclipse, parallel-processing, webdriver

I have to write test in java with selenium using eclipse. I have situation where i need to run simultaneously two browsers. I know there is TestNG, but for now i can't afford to use it. So my question is, is there a way to use

```
    new Thread
```

with only methods? For example:

```
    package test.test

    import...

    public class tests {
    public Thread t1, t2;

    @Before
    public void putUp() {
    //my code
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
    t1 = new Thread(usingT1);
    t2 = new Thread(usingT2);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    ...//rest of the code
    }

    public void usingT1(){
    //code of that method
    }

    public void usingT2(){
    //code of that method
    }

    @After
    public void putDown(){
    //my code
    }
```

I know there is a way to use class with Runnable element. If there is no way for using method could u give me a simple example of that class cause everything i find is showed in a weird way.

Thx for help
Janer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done; for example by using anonymous innerclasses:

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread( new Runnable() {
  @Override 
  public void run() {
  ... will happen in its own thread 
  }
});
```

Then you just call start() on your thread objects.

But the real question is: is it a good idea? And I think it is not. You are kind of-reinventing the wheel here; and whatever you will come up with ... will probably less good than any existing solution that does such things for you.

In the end, it depends on A) your skills and B) the things you actually want to do in parallel. And alone the fact that you have no idea how to something that simple makes me assume that your skills are not fit to do what you suggest here.

Comment: I just ask if it's possible like these. And yes my skills in Java are on low level that's why i ask. In C# i could do that the way i write. For what i want to do is use to run two browsers and in my site add two positions for one thing and check efficiency. In your opinion what way is best? with classes? Or to use TestNG in the end which I would have to learn with limited time i have now?

Comment: The question is how long the "thing that you intend to create" will exist. If we are talking about throw-away code; and your core requirement is "quick results"; then maybe my code snippet is enough to get you going.

Comment: So these type of code is for short term use. And for long term??

Comment: And for me for now its to get quick results.

Comment: Long term I suggest in using some framework that matches what you need.

Comment: You are welcome. But just for the record: these are kind of my *opinions*. When you come to the conclusion that whatever you create now is "good enough" long term, too - then take my advise as law that you absolutely have to follow. It is your product; it should be your judgement, you know the details better than I do.